# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(int)'

Tags: java, apache-beam, snappy

When I am trying to run my application I am getting below error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(int)'
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(Native Method)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.maxCompressedLength(Snappy.java:381)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:99)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:91)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.clone(SerializableUtils.java:117)

I am using snappy-java-1.1.9.0 jar.

Could anyone please suggest how to fix it?
```

Comment: For this kind of error, you need to provide your dependency configuration(pom.xml / build.gradle).

Comment: Hi Samabcde, the dependency is already added in the pom.xml.

Comment: I mean you edit your post to include dependencies section of your pom.xml,
because your libs may not be compatible to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Beam you are using?

If you check Beam 2.45.0 [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.45.0/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/beam/gradle/BeamModulePlugin.groovy#L731), it uses Snappy 1.1.8.4.

Likely that if you're bringing Snappy 1.1.9.0 and missing that method, they haven't made it backwards compatible.

Comment: Hi Bruno,  Beam version is 2.38.0 and it also uses snappy 1.1.8.4. But still I am getting the same error. Could there be any other reason?